# Sceneform: Render WebRTC media stream in to ExternalTexture

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to develop an AR app to help visual impaired people to make better their access conditions to a computer.

I am investigating on how AR can help HCI for visual disabilities, so, the application is using WebRTC to get computer Desktop to be magnified at AR environment using Sceneform.

I have successfully used the Sceneform example https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/chromakeyvideo, but, I have no idea of how to render the WebRTC stream directly to a ExternalTexture. -> https://github.com/judicapo/MUITSS-ARBE/tree/master/SampleApps/ARCK

I already tried some Stackoverflow answers, but, have not found the clue.

Thank you all for your replies, hope some one has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I have not worked with this. but I could think of a way on how to approach this.

Instead of chromaKey rendering on a texture, why don't you try a 'ViewRenderable'? using this, you can place any android View to a node. You just need to place a VideoView and do your webRTC magic. let me know if this works

https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables

AugmentedImage example - https://proandroiddev.com/arcore-sceneform-simple-video-playback-3fe2f909bfbc

ViewRenderable example - https://github.com/Hariofspades/ARExperiments/blob/master/AugmentedImages/app/src/main/java/com/hariofspades/augmentedimages/common/AugmentedImageNode.java

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was reading your suggestions, you are right Sceneform supports ViewRenderable, but, it has the restriction of not use a VideoView (In WebRTC SurfaceViewRenderer) as you can see here: 
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/9
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/75

What they suggest to use is their chomakey video example, but they are using a MediaPlayer instance in order to set a texture to draw frames.
Lastly the augmented images examples are using same strategy, MediaPlayer with a texture. Looking forward :)